# Make a formdropdown form

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to make dropdown form with multiple results from database. I have a list of cars in database and I want to make a dropdown form to select one from a little list. Im just learning a programing and I don't know how to do that. 
My code:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `cars`");

foreach ($query->result() as $row){
    echo 'Model: ' . $row->model;
    echo br(1);
    echo 'Opis: ' . $row->Opis;
    echo br(1);
    echo 'Rok produkcji: ' . $row->year;
    echo br(1);
    echo 'Cena za dzien: ' . $row->price .'zl';
    echo br(2);
}
```

I just want to show a results from $row->model. Something like this, but with my cars:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not able to understand your question. you may looking something like this

```
<?php $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `cars`"); foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{ ?>
<select>
<option value="<?php echo $row->model; ?>"><?php echo $row->model; ?></option>
<option value="<?php echo $row->Opis; ?>"><?php echo $row->Opis; ?></option>
<option value="<?php echo $row->year; ?>"><?php echo $row->year; ?></option>
<option value="<?php echo $row->price ; ?>"><?php echo $row->price; ?></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, I want do something like this. I will try explain that. $row->model is my car from my database. If I call $row->model I will get only one car from my list, but I got 4 cars in database and I want to be able select all of 4